# Is possible to install VirtualBox in an Ubuntu Server 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, server, virtualbox

I have an Ubuntu Server 14.04.

Is possible to install VirtualBox in this Ubuntu Server just using a command, without GUI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VirtualBox can be installed on the command line, directly from the Ubuntu repositories. This will install VirtualBox version 4.3.10:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

To update your package management system to use the most current packages.
Followed by:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

To install the main package and its dependencies.

After that I'd recommend getting the VirtualBox guest additions iso, with:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions-iso
```

The guest additions are required to ensure smooth running of your guest OS, when you build virtual machines.

It is normally necessary to obtain a VirtualBox extension pack to use all of the features of virtualbox, here is the virtualbox [old builds download page](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_4_3_pre24), the file is located under version 4.3.10 - Extension Packs - All Platforms. Alternatively the direct download link is [here](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.3.10/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.3.10-93012.vbox-extpack).

Answer (score 2):

You can install VirtualBox using `apt-get`, without a GUI:

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

From there, you will need to read the [VirtualBox manuals](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html) for command-line instructions.  You will probably want to configure them with an RDP server so that you can access them graphically (but remotely).